# Boost or TR1 equivalent of gsl_matrix and the like

Tags: c++, boost, open-source, tr1

I cannot use `gsl_matrix` because my app is closed source and, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842776/gpl-license-in-closed-source-application), if I used GPL code directly, I'd have to make my app open source. And that's a no-no from the higher ups.

So... Does Boost, or even better, TR1, have a library with classes equivalent to `gsl_matrix`, `gsl_vector` and other types from the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)? If there are such classes, how are they called?

**Edit:** I need to:

- Perform dense matrix-vector products and sums (like `gsl_blas_dgemv` and `gsl_blas_dgemm` do)
- Optionally, solve [quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) models.

Comment: what exactly do you need? There are many operations that can be performed on matrices and they can be used in many fields. Often there are specialized libraries per field.

Comment: @KillianDS, you're right. I added that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is [C interface for BLAS/LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/blas/faq.html#7). Some people find it 'hard' to deal with the call signatures which directly mirror the original BLAS ones.

If you're more into fancier side of things, there's [Boost uBLAS interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), there's [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), to name just two. Performance-wise, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Based on personal experience, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) is probably the better choice, as it has a lot more functionality than Boost uBLAS. Armadillo's syntax is also very similar to Matlab.